# Creating Repeative Fields inside my Form Symfony2

Tags: symfony

I am working on a college project where I want to take the attendance of all the students. I have created a model with 3 fields i,e date, present (boolean) and student_id. Now when I try to generate a form out of it, it will display me only these 3 fields. However I want all the students of the class. So I created a loop for students and created an array of attendance objects. Now I am stuck, I don't know how I can pass them to my TWIG file, and I am also confused if it ist the right way to do this. Here is my Model and Controller code

### FORM

```
namespace College\StudentBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder;

class StudentAttendanceType extends AbstractType
{
   public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
   {
     $builder
        ->add('date')
        ->add('present')
    ;
   }

   public function getName()
   {
     return 'college_studentbundle_studentattendancetype';
   }
}
```

### CONTROLLER

```
public function takeAttendanceAction($Department_Id)
{
    $students = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('CollegeStudentBundle:Student')
    ->findAll($Department_Id);

    foreach($students as $key => $student){

        $attendance[$key] = new StudentAttendance();
        $form[$key] = $this->createForm(new StudentAttendanceType(), $attendance[$key]);
    }

    $request = $this->getRequest();
    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {

        $form->bindRequest($request);
        if ($form->isValid()) {

            $em = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getEntityManager();
            $em->persist($attendance);
            $em->flush();
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('CollegeStudentBundle_index', array('id' => $Department_Id)));
        }
    }
    return $this->render('CollegeStudentBundle:StudentAttendance:take-attendance.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(), 'department' => $Department_Id, 'students' => $students,
    ));
}
```

How can I render the form in a way that it will display me all the students with a separate checkbox ?

### HTML.TWIG

```
{% block body  %}
<form  action="{{ path('CollegeStudentBundle_take_attendance',{'id':department} ) }}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }} name="acadimics-form" id="acadimics-form" >

{{ form_errors(form) }}
{{ form_row(forms[0].date) }}

<table id="mytabs" border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="2" width="100%" >
   <tr>
    <th> Enrolment No. </th>
    <th> Student's Name </th>
    <th> Present </th>
   </tr>
  {% for student in students %}
    <tr>
       <td> {{ student.enrolmentNo }} </td>
       <td> {{ student.firstname }} {{ student.lastname }} </td>
       <td> {{ form_row(form.present) }} </td>
        </tr>
  {% endfor %}
  {{ form_rest(form) }}
</table>

<input type="submit" value="Take Attendance"  />
</form>
  </div>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not tested. But there should be a little modification.
The loop in the controller:

```
foreach($students as $key => $student){

    $attendance[$key] = new StudentAttendance();
    $form[$key] = $this->createForm(new StudentAttendanceType(), $attendance[$key])->createView();
}
```

return the array:

```
return $this->render('CollegeStudentBundle:StudentAttendance:take-attendance.html.twig', array(
    'form' => $form, 'department' => $Department_Id, 'students' => $students,
));
```

In the template:

```
{% for sform in form %}
    {{ form_widget(sform) }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks for ur response, but this doesn't work. It gives the following error

Comment: An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Extension\FormExtension::renderWidget() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\Form\FormView, instance of Symfony\Component\Form\Form given, called in /opt/lampp/htdocs/college/app/cache/dev/twig/a0/4b/94e3cc19d73f275eee3e95d5d19d.php on line 19 and defined in /opt/lampp/htdocs/college/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Extension/FormExtension.php line 159") in CollegeStudentBundle:StudentAttendance:take-attendance.html.twig at line 2.

Comment: This works when i remove all content of my present twig file.. Can u please help me with the twig customisation as well. I am pasting the twig template file to my question as well

Comment: This structure will cause problem when you'll try to submit one of the forms. First, creating the view just after creating the form gives you no possibility to handle the request. And then multiple problems arise. Cerad's solution is actualy much better.

Answer (score 3):

I think you may be on the wrong track.  S2 already deals with arrays out of the box.

Read through:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html

You basically want to create a master ListofStudents form and then imbed a StudentAttendence form.  You can then pass your array of students to the master form and all the array processing will happen magically.

In your ListOfStudents form you will have something like:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('students', 'collection', array('type' => new StudentAttendenceType()));
```

Answer (score 1):

You return the variable `students` to the template and you're calling `student.firstname` in twig, it should be `students.firstname` and you should keep your `'form' => $form->createView()` in the return of your controller.

I think it should work better, hope this help!