# symfony2 display twice the fields of the form

Tags: php, forms, symfony, twig

I have a list of "hours" that workers passed on mandates. An admin can check them (checkbox)to add them to a bill, (but he can adapt the real hours)

So, I have an array of hour selected, in my controler I get the hours :

```
$hours = $repository->findBy(array('id' => $tabHour));
```

so `$hours` countain more than one hour, I thought that if I was creating a form with $hours, it will automaticly display the fields more than once..

```
foreach($hours as $key => $test){

    $billedHour[$key] = new BilledHour();
    $form[$key] = $this->container->get('form.factory')->create(new BillMandateForm(), $hour);
}
```

I tried to do like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10083730/creating-repeative-fields-inside-my-form-symfony2?answertab=active#tab-top). But it's not solved, cause if I return a collection of forms I can't do `'form' => $form->createView()`so I can't render the forms...

Comment: Hey, no answer I was still able to do it, with the way of relationship class (manytoone) cause a bill has many billedhours, so with this I could generate fields (and parse it in javascript).

But I still don't know how to display more than one form in a page, if I want to create 2 entities at the same time ??

Answer (score 0):

Try to pack all your form views in array

```
$billedHours = array();
$forms = array();
foreach($hours as $hour) {
    $billedHours[] = new BilledHour();
    $forms[] = $this->container->get('form.factory')->create(new BillMandateForm(), $hour);
}
```

Then, create array of rendered form views

```
$formsToRender = array();
foreach($forms as $form) {
    $formsToRender[] = $form->createView();
}
```

Then, pass this array to Twig:

```
...
'forms' => $formsToRender
...
```

And finally in Twig render each of form views from array:

```
{% for form in forms %}
    {{ form_row(form.id) }} {# or form_widget(form) if you want to render whole from instead of some fields #}
{% endfor %}
```

I hope this helps ;)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I thought I tried something like rendering the form like you did. I think I still had some problems, but as I said in the comment I used the relations to generate forms.